# C# Selenium WebDriver wait for some elements to be fully loaded before going on

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Here is what I would like to do via Selenium WebDriver :

1. Go to https://www.for-sale.ie/adidas
2. Click on a filter
3. Click on the first Ad after filtering is done

What it does instead is clicking on the first Ad before filtering (the whole page is not reloaded for filtering, just the Ad list)

```
var url = "https://www.for-sale.ie/adidas";
RemoteWebDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
_driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#jsFilterItems_2 > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > label > input")).Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("article > .box_product_item.art-div > .listview > .middle > h2")).Click();
```

The only way I found to make it work is to add a `Thread.Sleep` which is not the best solution. I also tried to manage timeouts but without success. Any suggestion?

Comment: You should use ExpectedConditions to wait for the page to be updated - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm

Comment: Great! Thank you! I will explain what I done thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found via Grasshopper in the comment :

```
var url = "https://www.for-sale.ie/adidas";
_driver = new FirefoxDriver();
_driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

var firstAd = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("article > .box_product_item.art-div > .listview > .middle > h2"));

_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#jsFilterItems_2 > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > label > input")).Click();

var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(firstAd));

_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("article > .box_product_item.art-div > .listview > .middle > h2")).Click();
```

First, I get the first ad of the page (before filtering) then I expect this ad to be no longer attached to the DOM via the `StalenessOf` function when I click on the filter. And I can finally get the filtered ad.

Comment: As this is my answer, I have to wait 2 days to accect it. I will do it tomorrow.